# Call to undefined method Laravel Defender

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm using Laravel 5.1.*. Installed [defender](https://github.com/artesaos/defender) and created my role 'admin'...But when will using the middleware 'needsRole' (in routes.php) or 'Defender::hasRole('admin')' (in controller) not working.

Message error

```
BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2093:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasRole()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure of two things use the trait in your model `Artesaos\Defender\Traits\HasDefender` and register the service provider then do a composer dump-autoload

Comment: lookup entrust by zizaco i believe is the author its a pretty solid package and has a lot to offer with a fluent api.